# How do I use dexOption in the experimental Gradle plugin?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting an *OutOfMemory* error while building my code. I tried adding the `dexOption` in my experimental *build.gradle* file like so:

```
model {

    def signConf = new String()

    android {
        compileSdkVersion = COMPILE_SDK_VERSION as int
        buildToolsVersion = BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "x.y.z.k"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = MIN_SDK_VERSION as int
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = TARGET_SDK_VERSION as int
            versionCode = VERSION_CODE as int
            versionName = VERSION_NAME
            multiDexEnabled = true
            testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


        }

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"

        }
    }
}
```

With the `dexOption` I get the following error:

```
Error:Cause:com.android.build.gradle.managed.AndroidConfig_Impl
```

How can I add the `dexOption` while compiling with the experimental Gradle plugin?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me, is to place the dexOptions outside the android{} block and name it as android.dexOption.

eg.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
          ...
        }

        ndk {
           ...
        }

        buildTypes {
           ...
        }

        productFlavors {
            ...
        }
    }
    android.dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize = "2g"
    }
}

dependencies {
...
}
```